# MySQL SUMIFS with Dates

Tags: sql, group-by, rmysql

Having difficulty with a SUMIFS scenario on MySQL

Here's my data:

```
CREATE TABLE opportunities
(close_date DATE NOT NULL,
sale_amount DECIMAL NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190101',100);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190115',115);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190210',150);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190212',180);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190306',200);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190315',220);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190422',250);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190428',260);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190509',300);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190521',310);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190601',325);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190630',375);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190703',400);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190716',500);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190813',550);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190814',575);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190909',625);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20190929',650);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20191004',700);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20191022',750);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20191112',800);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20191119',900);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20191202',950);
INSERT INTO opportunities VALUES ('20191216',975);
```

What I need to accomplish is to have 1 row per Month-Year (e.g. 2019-01, 2019-02, 2019-03, etc.) and for that row, I need to do a sum of the sale_amount for the previous 6 months. So 2019-12 will have a sale_amount equal to the sum of all sale_amounts with a close_date of July 1st 2019 thru Dec 31 2019.  Based, on the data that I have provided, I need my final results to look like this:

```
Month       Sale_Amount (Prev 6 Months)
2019-01     215
2019-02     545
2019-03     965
2019-04     1475
2019-05     2085
2019-06     2785
2019-07     3470
2019-08     4265
2019-09     5120
2019-10     6060
2019-11     7150
2019-12     8375
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(op.close_date, '%Y-%m'),
    SUM(CASE
    WHEN op.close_date >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(op.close_date, INTERVAL 5 MONTH) ,'%Y-%m-01')
        AND op.close_date <= LAST_DAY(op.close_date) THEN op.sale_amount
    END)
FROM opportunities op
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(op.close_date, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(op.close_date, '%Y-%m')
```

This doesn't work, it only returns the sum for that month

Actual results I'm getting:

```
Month       Sale_Amount (Prev 6 Months)
2019-01     215
2019-02     330
2019-03     420
2019-04     510
2019-05     610
2019-06     700
2019-07     900
2019-08     1125
2019-09     1275
2019-10     1450
2019-11     1700
2019-12     1925
```

I'm trying to convert this from an Excel spreadsheet, The formula below works exactly as I intend, but not sure how to translate to MySQL

```
SUMIFS($B$2:$B$500, --sum range
$A$2:$A$500,">="&DATE(YEAR(EOMONTH(A2,-6)+1),MONTH(EOMONTH(A2,-6)+1),1), --close_date >= than first day 6 months ago
$A$2:$A$500,"<="&DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(EOMONTH(A2,0)))) --close date <= last date of current month
```

Hope my question is clear enough, thanks in advance

Comment: Wich version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: @GMB Had to ask and apparently it's vers. 5.7.26... Just realized I'm screwed since the answer I received includes a window function, which apparently is not supported unless I'm in 8.0+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for MySQL < 8.0:

```
select d.close_month, sum(o.sale_amount) sale_amount
from 
    (select distinct date_format(close_date, '%Y-%m-01') close_month from opportunities) d
    inner join opportunities o
        on o.close_date < close_month + interval 1 month
        and o.close_date >= close_month - interval 5 month
group by d.close_month
order by d.close_month
```

This works by generating a list of distinct months, joining it with the table on the 6 last months, and then aggregating.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77bbfd3cdb1f5629d87978e2e91d2861)**:

```
close_month | sale_amount
:---------- | ----------:
2019-01-01  |         215
2019-02-01  |         545
2019-03-01  |         965
2019-04-01  |        1475
2019-05-01  |        2085
2019-06-01  |        2785
2019-07-01  |        3470
2019-08-01  |        4265
2019-09-01  |        5120
2019-10-01  |        6060
2019-11-01  |        7150
2019-12-01  |        8375
```

Comment: Sick!!  This works perfectly for me on MySQL 5.7.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(op.close_date, '%Y-%m'),
       SUM(op.sale_amount) as this_month,
       SUM(op.sale_amount) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(op.close_date) ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as running_6_months
FROM opportunities op
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(op.close_date, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(op.close_date, '%Y-%m');
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of using window functions, although I can't get a result running this with SQL Fiddle for some reason.  Aside from the mispelling of ORDER, I can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: SUM(SUM(op.sale_amount)) must be SUM(op.sale_amount)

Comment: @nbk Still not working for me on SQL Fiddle, hmmm.  It says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY MIN(op.close_date) ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as runnin' at line 3"

Comment: dbfiddle has much much more restrictions as my mysql server where it runs, soi try it at home server please

Comment: @user1452574 that error is caused by MySQL version. Window function only work on MySQL 8+. you can test fiddle here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hnGDQEvkZ7YaUoc7REsCKW/0

Comment: Yeah I'm actually not using 8.0 but version 5.7.26. That sucks, can't use this answer after all